# Prove that $(0,1)$ is cardinally equivalent to $[0,1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How's this done?

Also, I am wondering, are all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ cardinally equivalent to each other? If not, why not?

Comment: What do you know about cardinality? How can you obtain $(0,1)$ from $[0,1)$? As for your other question, have you considered the singleton subsets, $\{a\}$? Its cardinality is 1. What about the rationals? They are countable. What about any interval? They have cardinality of $(0,1)$ or equivalently the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: $(0,1) = \left((0,1)\setminus\{\frac1n\colon n=2,3,\ldots\}\right)\cup \{\frac1n\colon n=2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160738/28900) and [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/279298/28900). In the latter, you can see how one can actually construct such a map.

Comment: @snarski so then, does that mean all uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are cardinally equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, if $X$ is infinite and $x\in X$ then there is a bijection between $X$ and $X\setminus \{x\}$.

Let $x_0=x,x_1,...\in X$ be an infinite sequence of distinct elements of $X$. Then define $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
x_{n+1} & \text{if } x=x_n\\
x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This is the same as totori's answer, he just picks a specific sequence $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Shuchang's answer is a variation, since his map goes the other direction, but he is basically using $x_0=0, x_n=2^{-n}\text{ otherwise}$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f:[0,1)\to(0,1)$ such that
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
1-\frac{1}{n+1} & \text{if $x=1-1/n$ for some natural number $n$}\\
x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
You can prove that $f$ is bijection. So two sets have same cardinality.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa boss, how did you contrive that monstrosity of a function?! Please explain.

Comment: @JohanLiebert I saw this function at the past.

Comment: @JohanLiebert:  The fundamental idea is an important one-sweeping the uncomfortable item(s) under the rug by moving everything down the line.  It is the same idea as the bijection $[0,\infty)$ to $[1,\infty)$ by taking $n$ to $n+1$.  We just need to find a countable series of points and shift them all by $1$

Answer (score 2):

Define a mapping $f$ from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1)$ by
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0,&x=\frac12\\
\frac1{2^n},&x=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\\
x,&\text{otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$$
The mapping $f$ is bijective, which implies $\text{card}(0,1)=\text{card}[0,1)$.

Comment: I need the reasoning on how you contrived this function to be explained, please. Just seeing this answer, there's no way I could come up with my own answer to a similar question on an exam. I have no idea how you came up with. What matters to me is not the answer to the question, but understanding how to solve it myself.

Comment: Yes, The difference between them is only a point right? Do you know Hilbert hotel problem? The solution is translation. You need to move this single "guest" into some room and then move the guest in that room into another room again and again.

Comment: @Johan: Henning's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/279298/28900) discusses how to come up with such functions in general, by using an injection each way to construct a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

The question of bijections have been answered.

The second question, however, has gone mainly unnoticed. The answer is no. Almost trivially, $\varnothing$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ and it is certainly not of the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ itself.

Moreover, there are finite sets, and countably infinite sets which are also of different cardinalities from one another.

One can ask, if so, if $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is uncountable, is it necessarily of the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$? The positive answer to this question is known as "**The Continuum Hypothesis**", but the answer is that there is no provable answer. It is consistent with the usual axioms of mathematics that the answer is "yes", and it is consistent that the answer is "no".

Namely, there are universes of set theory in which the answer is positive, and no uncountable set of real numbers has a smaller cardinality than $\Bbb R$; but there are universes of set theory where the answer is no and there is an example for such set. But do note that these example are not sets which can be explicitly written by a formula, we can simply prove they exist in one way or another from set theoretical assumptions.